# Trying to understand scanLeft on trees in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm in a Coursera's course and I'm trying to understand the logic of the scanLeft on trees. 
we have the following code:

Here we have as an input a tree (without intermediate values, only with values in Leafs) and returns a tree with intermediate values (with values in nodes)

```
 def upsweep[A](t: Tree[A], f: (A,A) => A): TreeRes[A] = t match {
      case Leaf(v) => LeafRes(v)
      case Node(l, r) => {
           val (tL, tR) = parallel(upsweep(l, f), upsweep(r, f))
           NodeRes(tL, f(tL.res, tR.res), tR)
      }
 }
```

And the following code that given a tree with intermediate values (with values in nodes) returns a tree without intermediate values (a0 is the reduce of all elements left of the tree t).

```
 def downsweep[A](t: TreeRes[A], a0: A, f : (A,A) => A): Tree[A] = t match {
      case LeafRes(a) => Leaf(f(a0, a))
      case NodeRes(l, _, r) => {
           val (tL, tR) = parallel(downsweep[A](l, a0, f),
           downsweep[A](r, f(a0, l.res), f))
      Node(tL, tR) } 
 }
```

And finally the scanLeft code:

```
 def scanLeft[A](t: Tree[A], a0: A, f: (A,A) => A): Tree[A] = {
      val tRes = upsweep(t, f)
      val scan1 = downsweep(tRes, a0, f)
      prepend(a0, scan1)
 }
```

And my question is, why is necesary to use the upsweep method before downsweep?
With upsweep we generate the intermediate values and later with downsweep we "remove" (we dont need to use) them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually look more closely at this part

```
case NodeRes(l, _, r) => {
       val (tL, tR) = parallel(downsweep[A](l, a0, f),
       downsweep[A](r, f(a0, l.res), f))
```

what is l.res? why it is so necessary to have it?(it is created at upsweep) I recommend you to draw on a piece of paper step by step what exactly is being done by this algorithm with  easy function like (_ + _). Also it Is very good technique if you do not understand smth to do it, just go easy step by step and resolve it by yourself.

Comment: I understand how downsweep (and upsweep) works. Instead of start downsweep with a tree with values in nodes (this is the reason of using upsweep), it is not posible to start with a tree with only values in leaves? This would be a posible code of downsweep:

   `def downsweep[A](t: Tree[A], a0: A, f : (A,A) => A): Tree[A] = t match {
case Leaf(a) => Leaf(f(a0, a))
        case Node(l, r) => {
        val (tL, tR) = parallel(downsweep[A](l, a0, f),
         downsweep[A](r, f(a0, l.res), f))
        prepend(a0, scan1)
        }`